# The lower value from a tuple of words and values in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to write a function that chooses the tuple with the lower value and the tuple is formed by a word and a value.

For example, for a list of tuples like this one: [("CHURCH",262),("PENCIL",311),("FLOUR",175),("FOREST",405),("CLASS",105)], the function would return ("CLASS",105)

Can someone help me out? :)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foldl1 (\acc x -> if snd x < snd acc then x else acc) <your list>
```

You fold your list by comparing the current element of the list to the next one. If the second value of the next element if smaller than the value of the current element, it is the new value for the accumulator. Else the accumulator stays the same. This process is repeated until the entire list has been traversed.

Comment: Something like this was in my mind but I can't yet remember what fold(l/r) does. I think thats a cool example to demonstrate fold.

Comment: @OderWat A fold is a function which takes a (binary) function of the type (a -> b -> a) and a starting value. It then traverses a list from left to right (or right to left, it depends on the fold) and applies the function to the starting element (called the accumulator) and the current element and updates the accumulator to the result of that evaluation. Then the same process begins for the next element and so on...

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for the function `minimumBy` in the `Data.List` module.  It's type is

```
minimumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
```

In your case, it would also be useful to import `comparing` from the `Data.Ord` module, which has the type

```
comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
```

And this lets you give it an "accessor" function to create an ordering.  So in this case you can do

```
minimumSnd :: [(String, Int)] -> (String, Int)
minimumSnd = minimumBy (comparing ???)
```

I'll let you fill in the `???`, it should be quite easy at this point.  What would your accessor function passed to `comparing` be for your type?

---

If you wanted to write a custom function for this instead, I would suggest using the `fold` pattern.  We can also take this opportunity to make it safer by returning a `Maybe` type, and more general by not requiring it to be a list of `(String, Int)`:

```
minimumSnd :: (Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> Maybe (a, b)
minimumSnd = go Nothing
    where
        -- If the list is empty, just return our accumulator
        go acc [] = acc
        -- If we haven't found a minimum yet, grab the first element and use that
        go Nothing (x:xs) = go (Just x) xs
        -- If we have a minimum already, compare it to the next element
        go (Just currentMin) (x:xs)
            -- If it's <= our current min, use it
            | snd x <= snd currentMin = go (Just x) xs
            -- otherwise keep our current min and check the rest of the list
            | otherwise = go (Just currentMin) xs
```

Comment: One  more thing: is there a function similar to minimumBy that orders a list of tuples like that one in descending order?

Comment: @emic You'll want to use `sortBy`, you just need to provide it a function that compares the elements and returns them in the order you want.  A quick one-liner would be `sortBy (flip $ comparing snd)`.

Answer (score 1):

I am Haskell beginner but I wanted to find a working solution anyway and came up with:

```
minTup' :: [(String, Int)] -> Maybe (String, Int) -> (String, Int)
minTup' [] (Just x)= x
minTup' (x:xs) Nothing = minTup' xs (Just x)
minTup' ((s,n):xs) (Just (s',n'))
    | n < n' = minTup' xs (Just (s,n))
    | otherwise = minTup' xs (Just (s',n'))


minTup :: [(String, Int)] -> (String, Int)
minTup [] = error "Need a list of (String,Int)"
minTup x  = minTup' x Nothing

main = do
    print $ minTup [("CHURCH",262),("PENCIL",311),("FLOUR",175),("FOREST",405),("CLASS",105)]
    print $ minTup [("CHURCH",262)]
    print $ minTup []
```